# Shell: How to create a user with the same password with another user?

Tags: bash, shell, arch-linux, shell-script, bash-scripting

Linux has a user, root. 
It has a password, unknown to the shell script. 
No human can input anything for the script. 
The script wants to create a user, user001, with the same password with root.

How can this be completed by the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard Linux systems (using pam_unix and shadow-utils) use crypt(3) password hashes with a random salt, and store them in the "shadow password file" accessible by root.

Assuming both users are local (i.e. stored in /etc/passwd and authenticated against /etc/shadow):

1. Get the old user's password hash (using `getent shadow <user>`, or directly from /etc/shadow). The hash is in the 2nd field.
2. Add the new user.
3. Write the password hash back to the new user's shadow entry (using `useradd -p`, or `usermod -p`, or `chpasswd -e`, or directly to /etc/shadow).

For example:

```
pwhash=$(sudo getent shadow OLDUSER | cut -d: -f2)

sudo useradd -p "$pwhash" NEWUSER
```

Note that while `root` is always local, it is not generally guaranteed that *other* accounts on a Linux system will be local (e.g. the account might use Kerberos authentication with an inaccessible hash). So if you're cloning a non-root account, it's up to you to provide that guarantee.

Also note that the root account might have no password at all (i.e. only set up for local console access), or its password hash may be marked as 'locked'. The above process will copy that exactly.